# Encoding get_the_title() for Twitter share URL

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I am using a direct link with  a popup for a share button on Twitter:
`<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink());?>&amp;text=<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>&amp;via=username" target="_blank"`

With all the crazy social media plugins out there, this is the simplest and most direct way for me to implement a share button.

However, when there is an `&` in the title, the title will break the text that is supposed to show for the status. I understand you need to `urlencode()` the title, but when I do that, it displays the special characters in the status message.

Since you do not need a `+` for a `[space]` in the Twitter share now,  I need to replace any `&`'s with `&amp;`. However, it does not seem to work with `str_replace()`. It for some reasons outputs the HTML special characters. Doing something like `<?php echo str_replace('&', '&amp;', urldecode(get_the_title())); ?>` doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by "but when I do that, it displays the special characters in the status message"? What is the final HTML that you are outputting and how does it show up on Twitter?

Comment: It outputs the special characters into the actual status message. So, you can see for example here: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&text=%26%238216%3BMr.+Blah+%26%23038%3B+Mrs.+Blah&via=username

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`&` has a special meaning in URLs to separate several parameters. If your URL is `...a&b...`, that does not represent the text "a&b", it represents two separate parameters. To avoid that, you need to `urlencode` the text, which turns `&` into `%26`.

Encoding `&` to `&amp;` is only necessary for `&` characters in HTML, which you should not have in your text, since all `&`s are replaced by `%26`.

I don't know the intricacies of Wordpress, but I think `get_the_title()` returns a value that is already HTML escaped. Meaning, it contains `&amp;` instead of `&`, so that's the value that is being sent to Twitter if you send it just like that. What you want is to get the text without HTML entities, i.e. you need to HTML-decode it to turn `&amp;` back into the actual value `&`. The HTML-decoded value then needs to be URL-encoded, so it doesn't screw up your URL syntax.

Putting it all together, this should hopefully do it:

```
echo urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

There may be other ways to get the original title without HTML entities directly from Wordpress without needing to do the complicated `html_entity_decode` dance, but again, I don't know a lot about Wordpress.

---

PS: Since you're outputting that URL into an HTML context, you *should* HTML encode the URL again to make sure it doesn't break your HTML syntax. That's mostly for academic completeness though, `urlencode()` *should* not return anything that can break HTML syntax. But just for pedantic completeness, here:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(urlencode(html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I understand, which is why I initially encoded it, but the problem is that when I encode the entire text, the special HTML characters show in the actual status. See for example here: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com&text=%26%238216%3BMr.+Blah+%26%23038%3B+Mrs.+Blah&via=username

Comment: Why do you have special HTML characters in the URL to begin with? Again, what is the actual HTML that's being output?

Comment: I'm using `get_the_title()` so that I can Tweet something with the `text=get_the_title()`. There are occasionally `'` or `&` in the titles of the post, which is not unusual. The actual HTML that is being outputted is the encoded `get_the_title()`, but as I said before, the problem is that Twitter is outputting the special characters in the status. I've Googled this problem and no one seems to have a definite solution, as it is a known problem apparently.

^ And I just showed you the actual HTML being outputted.

Comment: So `get_the_title()` returns already HTML-escaped text? Then you need to HTML-decode that text before you URL-encode it. If the text you URL-encode contains the value `&amp;`, well, then that's the value that is sent to Twitter.

Comment: Tried both: `echo urldecode(urlencode(get_the_title)))` and `echo urlencode(urldecode(get_the_title)))`. The first one returns the same thing as mentioned above, and the second one returns unescaped characters.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, one of those answer that should have received a lot more upvotes than it already has. Great answer with stellar explanation. Saved me some headache.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer, I was getting 404 now problem solved! Thank you;